# JavaScript and CSS files won't work in html (spring boot app)

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, spring

I have a problem with a html file not 'loading' js and css files properly. This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create new snippet</title>
    <script src="static/js/send.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/button.css">
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="code_snippet" placeholder="//write your code here"></textarea><br/>
<button type="submit" onclick="send()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

It is supposed to take some input into the textarea tag and send it to a database when you click on the button. However, the function send() doesn't work at all. Also, the linked CSS doesn't work as well. This is my project structure:

[image]

This is the send() function:

```
function send() {
    let object = {
        "code": document.getElementById("code_snippet").value
    };

    let json = JSON.stringify(object);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", '/api/code/new', false)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(json);

    if (xhr.status != 200) {
        alert("Something went wrong!");
    } else if (xhr.status == 200){
        alert("Success!");
    }
}
```

This function works fine when I put it inside of script tag

Comment: Post your **actual code** here, not images of your code. And you didn't even post the function `send()` that you say doesn't work.

Comment: Is the HTML file where you are referencing the files the new_code.html

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the links are relative or absolute to the home directory.

/absolute path
and use without "/" for relative path

try to access css and js file links from browser.